# Python Ctypes - Writing to memory created by malloc

Tags: python, memory, ctypes

I have something like this:

```py
import ctypes

dll = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')

dll.malloc.argtypes = ctypes.c_size_t
dll.malloc.restype = ctypes.c_void_p

ptr: int = dll.malloc(100) # how do i write to this memory?
print(ptr) # gives a memory address
```

How do I set a value to that memory? Preferably a `ctypes.py_object`.

I'm aware that doing this in Python is a bad idea, but I'm just experimenting with breaking the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write to the pointer similar to C.  Cast the void pointer to something that can be dereferenced and write to it with Python or use `ctypes` to call a C function that can use the pointer.  A couple of examples:

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('msvcrt')  # Windows C runtime

# void* malloc(size_t size);
dll.malloc.argtypes = ct.c_size_t,
dll.malloc.restype = ct.c_void_p
# void free(void* ptr);
dll.free.argtypes = ct.c_void_p,
dll.free.restype = None
# char* strcpy(char* dest, const char* src)
dll.strcpy.argtypes = ct.c_char_p, ct.c_char_p
dll.strcpy.restype = ct.c_char_p

# casting to pointer to specific-sized array enables
# use of ".raw" and checks that array bounds aren't exceeded.
ptr = ct.cast(dll.malloc(10), ct.POINTER(ct.c_char * 10))
print(ptr.contents.raw)
# Note use of [:] to replace the entire array contents with a same-sized bytes object
ptr.contents[:] = b'abcdefghij'
print(ptr.contents.raw)

# char (*ptr)(10) isn't correct for strcpy, so cast to char*
dll.strcpy(ct.cast(ptr, ct.POINTER(ct.c_char)), b'ABCDEFGHIJ')
print(ptr.contents.raw)
dll.free(ptr)
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00'
b'abcdefghij'
b'ABCDEFGHIJ'
```